# Publish Google Sheets add-on for own domain only

Tags: google-sheets, publish, add-on

I am trying to publish my first Google Sheets add-on for just the users of my domain but I get this error 
"Chrome Web Store system error, please try again later " 
when I try to "Deploy as Sheets add-on"

Is this because I need to ask my domain's admin to allow me to publish ?
 If so , where can he find that settings ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found that I have to click 'pay fee now' just like I would do for publishing to public .After that my developer settings are displayed and it works.